# Batch Open different programs depending on location

Tags: c#, batch-file, file-extension, file-type

Is there Batch code/c# for if say for example, I have a anime folder and a movies folder and I want to watch anime with program A and movies with Program B.
Is there a way I can get the same file type (.mkv/.avi/.mp4) to open with different programs depending on its folder/hard drive location?
I assume I will have to set all video file types to open this batch but I do not know the arguments to enter.
Thanks.

Comment: You can achieve this by writing an executable which uses the provided arguments and identifies the path, then starts the appropriate application. The goal is a little odd though, is it really necessary to have separate applications for anime and regular shows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write a batch file that launches the appropriate application based on the folder, like so:

```
IF /I "%~dp1"=="C:\anime\" programA.exe %*
IF /I "%~dp1"=="C:\movie\" programB.exe %*
```

Then right-click on one of your files and choose **Open With - Choose Default Program**, then browse to the .bat file you just created.  Make sure the checkbox "**Always use the selected program to open this kind of file**" is checked.

From now on, you can simply double-click the file and the correct program will be launched.

Answer (score 0):

If you have located your file, you can create a FileInfo object for it, and check it's Directory path by:

```
FileInfo file = new FileInfo(@"c:\Anime\Anime.avi"); 
string dirPath = file.DirectoryName;

if (dirPath == @"c:\Anime")
{
  //Open with VLC
}
else if (dirPath == ...something else...)
{
  //Open with something else
}
```

Comment: that would be ok, but I am doing this for a shortcut to doing "right click open with", what I would prefer to do is set .filetype default program to be this batch/c# that way I would not have to edit the code for each file I wish to open